# How to unset a DS model property in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a scenario when if certain conditions are met, I need to unset a model property, so it wouldn't be saved to the server when I do a `PUT`.

Is there any way to delete a property for a DS model in Ember? (i.e. set it to undefined)

I don't think setting it to `null` would help in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the model's property to undefined explicitly?

```
someModel.itsProperty = undefined;
```